# Mixing modules and namespaces

Tags: typescript

I've an Angular 2 project that uses modules (external ones) and want to use a library that use namespaces ([automapper-ts](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)).

How have I to include or import it?. I've looked at documentation about modules and namespaces. But it's not clear for me how to use a library that only uses namespaces in a project that uses modules.

Answer (score 1):

If a library doesn't export anything to the UMD, AMD or CommonJS format, then you just have to load it (with a `<script>` tag for example) or to require it from your loader/bundler. The namespace will be available the old fashioned way: from a global variable.

In order to compile your code, depending of your configuration, you'll have to make the compiler find the declaration file of your library. [This one, I guess](https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/blob/master/dist/automapper-declaration.d.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Although the library has not been designed as a modular library, it is not very hard to get the library working with Angular 2+. I have answered this question before when an issue about this was created on the package's GitHub page: https://github.com/loedeman/AutoMapper/issues/17.

For clarity (and indexing), here is my proposed solution:

I just created a basic Angular app using Angular CI. Getting AutoMapper to function correctly is quite easy, if you follow the guidelines for using an 3rd party library (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation). An excerpt:

1. Install the automapper-ts library using npm:
   `npm install automapper --save`
2. Add the following line to the file typings.d.ts:
   `declare module 'automapper-ts';`
3. Add the automapper-ts minified JS file to the scripts array in angular-cli.json:
   `"../node_modules/automapper-ts/dist/automapper.min.js"`
4. Import the module created in step 2 in your module/component file:
   `import { } from 'automapper-ts';`

Now you should be able to use the automapper global variable as documented.

Ragarding typing: I discovered the AutoMapper's package.json lacks the typings property in package.json. It will be there shortly (will for sure commit it right after this post), but in the mean time you could add it yourself, just below the main property:

`"typings": "./dist/automapper",`

Comment: Some formatting (quote, list & code markdown) would really help here.